# How do i create a php provider server for apns iphone app?

Tags: php, iphone, ios, apple-push-notifications

I have viewed and studied many tutorials including Apple Document but i can't find a way to create my own service provider server for apns. In this link `http://www.raywenderlich.com/3443/apple-push-notification-services-tutorial-part-12` they gave us a sample php server and hard code our device token to receive the push notifications. But, am looking for `to create a php server` and how to host the php server in local web site. Am not a well familiar in db/server side work that's why am struggling. Can anyone please explain me or `suggest any tutorials to create a php server and host the server in local? How to save all device tokens in the server from our device?` Please help me. Thanks in advance. I have spent two days in this topic please save my day. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to create a server your self, there is [an easier ready to use solution](http://urbanairship.com/)

Comment: Hi Lefteris thanks for your answer. But, am not a owner for the app. My client wants to develop his own server and wants to maintain himself. That's why am looking a way to create our own server .php and how to save all device tokens in itself. Can you please answer me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using Urban Airship in a client commercial app. creating your own PHP server for delivering push is very easy and the tutorial you are reading is excellent. You need to ask a specific question/problem if you have and not such a generic one

Comment: Yes Mr.Lefteris you are right. But, i have used Google to find a way to create own php server for apns yet i didn't find any useful tutorial. If you know can you please help me. Thanks.